# How to interact between two tables on both directions in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets in my Excel project:
In "Sheet1", I have a big data table, with 4 columns:
DataTable[Country], DataTable[Brand], DataTable[Parameter], DataTable[Calculated].

On "Sheet 2" I have a dashboard. I have there a table called FilteredTable that presents the data from DataTable. I have there a drop down command that lets the user select country, and the table is filtered accordingly.

I want that the FilteredTable will not only show data from the original DataTable, but to let the user to change the [Parameter] column. When changing it, I want that the [Calculated] column in both tables will be updated accordingly. If the user will change the country, then the FilteredTable will show the parameter that is stored in DataTable for that combination of [Country] and [Brand]. And if the user will get back to the first country, the displayed parameter will be the last one that the user entered.

I am a bit confused how to do it.
What I have done so far is:

1) to read into FilteredTable rows from DataFilter, using a formula array. I am mirroing this way [country],[brand] and [calculated]

2) in the DataTable[paramter], I read from FilteredTable[parameter] the same way, with a formula array.

It works fine, untill I change a country, and then the parameters in FilteredTable are already do not match the new country, and in DataTable, the parameters for the old country where changed to 0.

I'm in a logical loop. Is there a way out?

Thanks

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using 3 tables instead of 2? This would be: the original data table, a table which pulls in all values created through manual entry from the display table, and the display table itself.

In VBA, create a function which runs each time a formula is changed in the display table. That function should take the new data from the user, and copy the altered row onto the 'manual entry' table. For the display table itself, you could either recalculate manually through VBA every time a change is made, or have a formula which looks to see whether there is data in the manual table. If there is data in the manual table, that is where the value is pulled from. Otherwise, data is pulled from the original data table.